# How to differentiate Archive and Delete Operation in Microsoft Graph API Deltaquery for Mailbox messages?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail, delta

Graph Explorer Response for message deletion :

```
 "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
 "id": "AEBwDPd7FzHxsTSay..............kAAA68v55AAA="
    "@removed": {
           "reason": "deleted"
                }
```

Graph Explorer Response for message Archive:

```
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
"id":"AAMkAGYwZTllZD...........zHxsTSakAAA5nzbXAAA=",
       "@removed": {
            "reason": "deleted"
                   }
```

How to differentiate archive and delete Operation as it gives same kind of response to deltaquery?

Comment: I can think about the closest one here... you can check the odata.nextlink where the item is located or in which folder (regular Outlook folders, say mailfolders or special folder like archive).

Comment: I used delta to get changes on messages. I tried to match the id of message(which i stored) with the message in deleted or archived folder to identify whether it is deleted or archived but the Id of message gets changed when the message is moved to any other folder. Is there any other approach to differentiate Archive and Delete Operation ?

Comment: If you enable immutable message ids that should help match up. The other thing that we do is we cache the `internetMessageId` and use that as another reference to de-duplicate

Comment: Ever found a solution to this?